# Is there only one Diaspora pod program?

Tags: diaspora

Is there only one program for hosting a Diaspora pod, or are there several implementations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diaspora is the name of one Ruby implementation for a decentralized social networking tool, just like Firefox is the name of one implementation for a web browser.

If you want one written in another language, it won't be Diaspora and it won't load any Diaspora plugins (just like Chrome doesn't load Firefox plugins) but, if it speaks the [same protocols](https://diaspora.github.io/diaspora_federation/), it will be able to talk to Diaspora.

Since that looks like the basic [OStatus](https://ostatus.github.io/spec/OStatus%201.0%20Draft%202.html) family of protocols, I'd say that [anything that supports them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OStatus#Projects_using_OStatus) should be able to inter-operate with Diaspora.

Comment: I was under the impression that both the Ruby implementation and the protocol were called Diaspora.

Comment: They may internally refer to some superset of OStatus as Diaspora for all I know, but from what I'm seeing, Diaspora communicates between instances using the plain ordinary OStatus suite. (WebFinger, LRDD, hCard, Activity Streams, PubSubHubbub, Salmon, OAuth, etc.)

Comment: The first major difference, which is probably what makes it impossible to reply to Diaspora posts on OStatus instances, is that OStatus doesn't use hCard, and I'm guessing the Salmon implementations differ too (as de facto OStatus does non-standard Salmon signatures).

Answer (score 2):

These platforms can also talk Diaspora protocol and connect to Diaspora pods:

- [Hubzilla](https://hubzilla.org/) (formerly Red Matrix) (PHP)
- [Friendica](https://friendi.ca/) (formerly Friendika, formerly Mistpark) (PHP)
- [Socialhome](https://socialhome.network/) (Python)

Discontinued:

- Pyaspora (Python)

Regarding OStatus: The answer above is not entirely correct.

Yes, there is a lot in common with OStatus (WebFinger, XRD, hCard, Atom, ActivityStreams) but the way posts are sent between Diaspora pods is somewhat different than the way OStatus platforms such as GNU Social, Pleroma or Mastodon do it.

Sharing of posts in Diaspora is not the same as "following" a feed on an OStatus platform and pods send each other Salmon slaps directly rather than via PubSubHubbub.

Answer (score -3):

https://github.com/diaspora/diaspora/wiki/Installing-and-Running-Diaspora

> This document contains technical information for installing the necessary software to run a pod yourself, either for development, or as a new pod on the Diaspora network.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I realise that anyone can run their own Diaspora pod, but is there only one implementation of the pod server program?

Comment: It looks to be a fairly standard Ruby/MySQL/other_dependencies system (see preparing your system section) so yes, the implementation is the same. But it can be installed on Linux/OS X/Windows.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. I'm wondering if there is only one program (let's call it `diaspora-pod-ruby`) that can run a pod, or if there are others (e.g. `diaspora-pod-perl`) as well.

Comment: @Tim, Diaspora is written in Ruby on Rails (https://github.com/diaspora/diaspora/wiki/An-Introduction-to-the-Diaspora-Source) only. Hope this clears things up.